# robocop.yml won't ignore files for code checking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I installed gem 'rubocop', '~> 0.67.2' on my rails app and now I want to add some files to rubocom.yml/Exclude so that Rubocop don't track them.
I put it in the root of my app

rubocop.yml

```
AllCops:
  Exclude:
  - 'db/**/*'
  - 'config/**/*'
  - 'script/**/*'
  - 'bin/{rails,rake}'
```

but still when I run 'rubocop' command in my terminal, those files are still shown as tracked. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `.yml` formatting is incorrect, you need to have indentation for array elements, like

```
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - 'db/**/*'
    - 'config/**/*'
    - 'script/**/*'
    - 'bin/{rails,rake}'
```